# Whitelisting Gmail SMTP in CSF

Tags: apache-2.4, firewall, smtp, whitelist, csf

In my csf.deny, I have `0.0.0.0/0` blocked to prevent requests being sent to the raw server IP. This creates issues with sending e-mails. I utilize Google SMTP to send e-mail. I can't seem to figure out how to whitelist Gmail's SMTP while blocking `0.0.0.0/0`. My Gmail SMTP settings are correct, and send e-mail properly when I don't have `0.0.0.0/0` blocked.

I've tried a variety of things to try to allow Gmail's SMTP through, including:

- Only blocking incoming requests to all ports from `0.0.0.0/0` with no rules on outgoing requests
- Performing `nslookup smtp.gmail.com`, and whitelisting those IPs
- Whitelisting `smtp.gmail.com` in `csf.dyndns`

No matter what I try, if `0.0.0.0/0` is in `csf.deny`, e-mail will not be sent. Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you want to share a little more context/configuration and the direction of connections, its unclear why you would employ *IPv4* firewall rules to configure your *SMTP-level* policies. Which probably encompass SMTP traffic in both IPv4 & IPv6 anyway. Who initializes the connection? What criteria do you *actually* want to base your decisions on, as it sounds like IP addresses were merely an attempt to match something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whitelist `smtp.gmail.com` in `csf.dyndns`, and in `csf.conf` verify you have `DYNDS = "300"`, and `DYNDNS_IGNORE = "1"`

- `DYNDNS` is the number of seconds for CSF to poll for a change in the IP address of your specific FQDN (smtp.gmail.com)
- `DYNDNS_IGNORE` will ignore `csf.dyndns` IP addresses from lfd blocking.

Comment: Thanks. Apparently the issue was with the DYNDNS, and DYNDNS_IGNORE values